# Send SMS in iOS

Tags: swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am brand new in `iOS` developing and `xCode`.
Previously i developed android and i know i should work with Intent to make call and send SMS in android App.
Now i want to develop a simple App that when i press a `Button` it send a `SMS` to a specific number.
So i installed a `Mac OS 10.11` `VM` on  my `Ubuntu`.
And could connect connect my `iPhone` 5 to that and run my simple `Hello World` App in real `iPhone` Device and not `simulator`.
Now i created a `Button` in `StoryBoard` and make a funcion by following this article : 
[Send SMS Message Toturial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/send-sms-messages-tutorial-ios8-swift)

Also look at other links and was similar.
Here is my simple `ViewController.swift`.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Send button pressed") //display a text to make sure is calling

        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
            let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            controller.body = "TestMessage "
            controller.recipients = ["xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx"] // sending for two numbers
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

        switch (result.rawValue) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
            print("Message was cancelled")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        case MessageComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
            print("Message failed")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        case MessageComposeResultSent.rawValue:
            print("Message was sent")
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

And also created a `Simple` Button and link that to `sendMessage` above.
When i run the app, displays the button and when i press it, it seems it is doing something, but the SMS is not sent.
Any Idea??
I really appreciate it.

Update : As our friend said i added `print("Send button pressed")` in sendMessage `Button`, so i find out the button call `sendMessage` when i press it.

Comment: Can you put `print("Send button pressed")` in your `sendMessage` function? If you don't see that message in your console, the function is probably not getting called.

Comment: I added this line before and after if in SendMessage funtion, where should is see that print??
I cant see in debug area or in iphone screen,
Now what should i do?

Comment: Did you connect your button from the storyboard to the code?

Comment: Yeah, i did, i pressed control button and then click on button and drag it to ViewController and now that is connected to sendMessage function.

Comment: What do you mean by "it seems it is doing something"?

Comment: sorry sir, now i see the log, it displays the text i inserted in sendMessage function, i mean this method works : 
print("Send button pressed")

Comment: Can you update your question with the print statement I gave?

Comment: I did this and when i press button i saw the text in output console of xCode.

Comment: I mean can you put the code in the question above? So that I can see where you placed it

Comment: @kabiroberai I did sir

Comment: What happens if you put the `print` statement inside the `if` block?

Comment: @kabiroberai    In debug area and All Output part, it display the text("Send button pressed") when i press button.

Comment: put the `print` inside of  `if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {...}`

Comment: Do you mean that it does it even when it's inside?

Comment: What do you see when you press the button?

Comment: @kabiroberai : I did not clear the first print before if and now put print after if statement, now display twice,
The text is displaying twice.

Comment: Yeah, it does the event.
The event is calling.

Comment: What do you see on your iPhone's screen?

Comment: In the screen,It seems The button goes down and again come up in first place.

Comment: @kabiroberai No idea?

Comment: I'm cross-referencing the tutorial to check what's different in your code

Comment: @kabiroberai Another thing, there was ! exactly after controller: MFMessageComposeViewController in messageComposeViewController in that toturial, xCode gives me warning to delete the ! 
Now i added "!" again and did not take care to xCode warning, but still no success.
And i also i give the number completely. with no - or _ or anything.
My country code and the mobile number.

Comment: @kabiroberai : The link had problem, I edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally did it, I mixed up two solutions, 
First of all,i changed the function of `sendMessage` and renamed it to `sendText`, in this way :

```
    @IBAction func sendText(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        controller.body = "Text Body"
        controller.recipients = ["xxxxxxxxxxx"]
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And the protocol of `MessageComposeViewController` is  :

```
func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
    switch (result.rawValue) {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled.rawValue:
        print("Message was cancelled")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultFailed.rawValue:
        print("Message failed")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    case MessageComposeResultSent.rawValue:
        print("Message was sent")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

And then click on the button in storyboards, and press `control` key and drag the button to ViewController and select the `sendText` function, now it works correctly.

Thx to my Friend @Kabiroberai for help and give some time.